# Spring 3 Validation and internationalization

Tags: validation, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I use this link to config my project's validation:
[Spring 3 Validation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch05s07.html)

And I added the following dependency:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

It works fine,but I have a internationalization issue,I am using Chinese, but I found there is no zh_CN exists in 
hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final.jar.
Is there another option?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the latest beta release?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.Beta1</version>
</dependency>
```

[This link](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HV-413) says that the Chinese translation work that has only just been finished in this version. There is a `ValidationMessages_zh_CN.properties` file inside the .jar so hopefully it contains what you need.

Comment: Added the latest beta release,and got the following error:The POM for org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.2.0.Beta1 is missing, no dependency information available.

Comment: Sounds like the JAR could not be found. Maven should have given you an error if it could not find a JAR file. How have you configured Maven to obtain JAR files? Have you added the [JBoss Maven Repository](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/) to your project? [4.2.0.Beta1](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/4.2.0.Beta1/) looks present and correct to me.